# Bash behavior after sleep in a loop receives SIGTSTP

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, signals

I have a bash script `sleep_loop.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in $(seq 1 100)
do
    sleep 1000
done
echo after_loop
```

Now I run this script using the command `bash sleep_loop.sh`. Then I open another terminal, get the PID of the `sleep` process and store it in `pid_of_sleep`, and run `kill -SIGTSTP $pid_of_sleep`. The result is that the job `bash sleep_loop.sh` is suspended in the original shell (which can be resumed using `fg`), as expected.

However, if I run the script using `bash -i sleep_loop.sh` so that the bash executing the script is in interactive mode, and repeat the above steps to send `SIGTSTP` to the `sleep` process, then the original terminal echos `after_loop` before the whole script is terminated. So it seems that after `sleep` exits from `SIGTSTP`, the bash running the script breaks out of the loop.

Here are my questions:

(1) What causes bash to behave differently in interactive and non-interactive mode after `sleep` receives `SIGTSTP`?

(2) In interactive mode, why does bash just breaks out of the loop without terminating the whole script after `sleep` receives `SIGTSTP`, even if the script does not contain any `break` statement?